# Change Gradle mavenCentral URL to My repo

Tags: android, gradle, maven-central

While working with Gradle in my country, download jars from maven central is a very timely-costed work.
**I wanna change the mavenCentral to maven-nexus:**
which means whenever I use mavenCentral it **always** points to **[oschina](http://maven.oschina.net/content/groups/public/)**

------edit------
**I have lots of projects with mavenCentral, so I do not want change each file.**

Now in new scripts I use maven{ url ...}
Any easy way??

Any one can hlep?
Thanks!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The easiest way to apply this change for all projects is to use an gradle init script that forces the use of the oschina repository instead of mavenCentral. you can put this:

```
allprojects{
    repositories {
        all { ArtifactRepository repo ->
            println repo.url.toString()
            if ((repo instanceof MavenArtifactRepository) && repo.url.toString().startsWith("https://repo1.maven.org/maven2")) {
                project.logger.warn "Repository ${repo.url} removed. Only $coporateRepoUrl is allowed"
                remove repo
            }   
        }
        maven { 
            url "http://maven.oschina.net/content/groups/public" 
        }
    }
}
```

into an gradle init file. 
Now you can use this by calling "gradle build -I yourInitFile.gradle" or you put this logic into a `init.gradle` file stored in your gradle home directory in `USER_HOME/.gradle/` directory. Now this will be picked up by every gradle invocation without explicitly setting `-I`

Another option is to create a custom gradle distribution where this file is store in the init.d directory of the distribution.

Answer (score 8):

Its easy! Instead of this:

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

Use this:

```
repositories {
    maven {
        url "https://..."
    }
}
```

Comment: You could also try `jcenter()`, see this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24852219/android-buildscript-repositories-jcenter-vs-mavencentral

Comment: @Toochka Thanks for your answer,but this is not really what i want. I have edit my question.

Comment: @acntwww Do you want to use the same url and (if needed) to change it in *only* one place?

Comment: @Toochka I have got the exact answer and ticked. That is what I want. THX!

Answer (score 2):

Just set up the repository in build.gradle file in your module's directory, like this:

```
repositories {
    maven { url "http://maven.oschina.net/content/groups/public" }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer,but this is not really what i want. I have edit my question.

Answer (score 1):

If you have lots of dependencies (i.e. in all `build.gradle` files) and for repository urls you are using

```
repositories {
    maven {
        url "https://www.myrepourl.com"
    }
}
```

but you want to change that url in only one file then do the following:

- Create `gradle.properties` file and there add this line: `REPO_URL=https://www.myrepourl.com`
- In all other `build.gradle` files copy the following:

  ```
  repositories {
      maven {
          url project.REPO_URL
      }
  }
  ```

You can add & use more properties in this way.
This worked like charm for me. Cheers!

Comment: Have you figured it out?

Comment: Is the question directed to me?