# Android studio error with gradle 2.0.0-beta6

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I've got a project with a shared lib. The folder structure is the following:
`RootProjects` that contains the folders `lib` and `app`.

In my settings.gradle I have

```
include ':app', ':..:lib:app'
```

and in build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile project(':..:lib:app')
}
```

Now if I switch from:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'
```

to

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-beta6'
```

I receive the following error from Android Studio:

```
cannot change dependencies of configuration ':..:lib:classpath' after it has been resolved
```

Comment: Did you try with the latest version (2.0.0-beta6)?

Comment: @Gaëtan same problem

Comment: Check that the actual names of you lib and app folders do not start with a capital letter.

Comment: @RaGe I created a new project called "example" lowercase and a new library project called "lib" lowercase. Same problem. It's fully broken.

Comment: Sorry, I got it the otherway around, needs to be a starting capital letter. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35013614/745574 If that doesn't help can you upload your sample project to github?

Comment: @RaGe It doesn't work but it seems the problem is the ':..:' part. If I create a symbolic link in the app folder to point to library project and then I use in settings. gradle include ':app', ':MyLibraryProject:mylibrary' instead of include ':app', ':..:MyLibraryProject:mylibrary' gradle builds.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your local gradle distribution is corrupted. Check the projects and make sure all gradle files point to the same gradle version(2.0.0-beta6 in your case). Close Android Studio delete `.gradle` folder from your pc (the folder located in your home directory of your computer). Then open the project again.