# Fabric and new gradle 2 released

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle, twitter-fabric

Yesterday I updated Android Studio 1.5 to Android Studio 2 and since that update my project can't be run.

I have this error:

> Error:Cannot change dependencies of configuration ':android:classpath'
>   after it has been resolved.

As I see it, I think that the error comes from my `Build.gradle` (project)

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'
    classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
}
```

I changed it to:

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.+'
    classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:2.+'
}
```

It still doesn't work. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Have you looked [at this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35013614/503508)?

Comment: Thanks, I looked that and commented some lines. Now it compiles, but fabric doesn't work.  
`buildscript {   
repositories {   
    jcenter()  
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }  
}  
  
dependencies {  
    //classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.+'  
    //classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:2.+'  
}`  
It seems that new version doesn't accept classpath on dependencies...

Answer (score 0):

I've also updated to 2.0 and uses fabric too.

here's the buildscript and it works well.

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0'
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}
```

you can have a try :)