# gradle not sync in android studio by Jcenter()

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, gradle-dependencies

In my Android studio when I want to sync online gradle with  JCenter()  in gradle it wont sync and failed that you are behind proxy !! and I never use proxy but if I use  maven { url  'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2'} instead of JCenter() in gradle file it will sync . I dont know why ?!! what should I do to sync with Jcenter()

Comment: provide you gradle file code too

Comment: i mean the code that you have written in your gradle working and non-working one.

Comment: I dont use specefic code  in gradle.when I build new android project in android studio the defualt gradle has Jcenter

Comment: which gradle version and which android studio?

Comment: android studio 2.1.1 gradle 2.10 in setting but in classpath 2.1.0

Comment: so what should I do?

Comment: i am assuming that you are not setting proxy setting in gradle-wrapper.

Comment: set Use default gradle wrapper in preferences and edit Project\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties files field distributionUrl like this

distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.10-all.zip

Comment: check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24852219/android-buildscript-repositories-jcenter-vs-mavencentral

Comment: thanks alot I will check that

Comment: I did what you said but when I set default gradle wrapper and I sync gradle it automatically change to local gradle